# making a navigation app in android but Navigation-ui-0.30.0 cannot resolve

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mapbox, mapbox-android

i am making navigation app using mapbox. but i am adding navigation-ui-0.30.0 dependency.it show this error  (Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:5.0.0)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP955.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the following entry in your top level gradle script:

```
  maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
```

See installation instructions [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/#add-the-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add maven repository inside "allprojects" script in  build.gradle(project level), I think you add the repository inside "buildscript". Check the following couple of line you have or not. If you have not then simply add them.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
}
```

}

Now you have to add two dependencies in you gradle.build(app level)

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.32.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.32.0'
```

Now sync, make sure internet connection. Hope it will works fine then.